# How to install Google Earth or DraftSight for 64-bit OS?

Tags: google-earth, architecture

I have Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit and can neither install Google Earth nor DraftSight, because it gives me error of architecture. However, both the softwares are for 64-bit.

How do I install them correctly?

> **Original Text (Portuguese) - It was translated using Google Translate**
>
> Boa tarde:
>
> Tenho o Ubuntu 12.10 a 64 bytes e não consigo instalar o Google Hearth
>   nem o Draftsight, porque me dá erro de arquitectura. Ambos os
>   softwares são para 64 bytes. Como posso instalar correctamente?
>
> Obrigado
>
> Bruno

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd> and then paste these lines one by one ,

```
wget http://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Good afternoon:

I have Ubuntu 12.10 to 64 bytes and can not install Google Hearth nor DraftSight, because it gives me error of architecture. Both softwares are for 64 bytes. How do I install correctly?

thank you

Bruno

Comment: I have given the 64-bit software only . execute them and let me know what you got.